# How to permute an array of integers without generating mirrored permutations (Java)

Tags: java, permutation, brute-force, traveling-salesman

I have written a method to permute an array of integers in java. However I could not figure out how I can prevent finding mirrored permutations.
For example I want all permutations of [1,2,3]. These would be:

```
[1,2,3]
[1,3,2]
[3,1,2]

[3,2,1]
[2,3,1]
[2,1,3]
```

The three last permutations are mirrored permutations, that I do not want to find at all. The reason for this is, that I am trying to implement a brute force solution for the traveling salesman problem. By discarding the mirrored permutations I could save some time, as it does not matter in which direction the tour is performed. The cost of the tour would be the same.

My idea was following: As seen in the example above, in the mirrored permutations the 2 is always in front of the 1. If I iterate through the array and find the 2 but not yet the 1, it means that the 1 is saved at a later index. Which means I can stop this permute. However I can not figure out how to perform this check. Moreover I do not know if this approach is the best way to solve this problem.
How can I perform this check? Are there better approaches?

```
public void bruteforce(Graph g) {
    int[] elements = new int[g.size()];
    int length = g.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i] = i;
    }

    permute(elements, length);

}

public void permute(int[] elements, int length) {
    if(length == 1) {
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(elements));
        }
    }else {
        for(int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
            permute(elements, length-1);

            if(length % 2 == 1) {
                swap(elements, 1, length-1);
            }else {
                swap(elements, i, length-1);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void swap(int[] elements, int firstElement, int secondElement) {
    int tmp = elements[firstElement];
    elements[firstElement] = elements[secondElement];
    elements[secondElement] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: How do you define mirrored permutation when N is even?

Comment: I have not defined anything for the mirrored permutation yet, because I do not know how. I am stuck at this point somehow.

Comment: Perhaps you mean two permutations that are the reversed image of each other? So
1234 and 4321 are "mirrored" ?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. I do not want this permutations to be printed out. And it would be cool, if it is possible to dismiss a swap if it gets clear that a permutation will be mirrored

Comment: For `N` elements, instead of `N!` permutations you will have `(N!) / 2` which is insignificant for non trivial `N`. Still interested in this optimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a DTO class 'Permutation' with a equals method to compare normal and reversed array
and save each Permutation in a `Set` in this way reversed array will match as repeated and be omitted

```
 ...
 Set<Permutation> permutations = new HashSet<>();

 public void permute(int[] elements, int length) {
    if(length == 1) {
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            permutations.add(new Permutation(elements));
         }
...

public class Permutation {

    private Integer[] elements;

    public Permutation(Integer... elements) {
    this.elements = elements;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    return elements.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }

    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    Permutation other = (Permutation) obj;
    // reversed elements
    List<Integer> revCurElements = Arrays.asList(this.elements);
    Collections.reverse(revCurElements);

    if (Arrays.equals(this.elements, other.elements) || Arrays.equals(revCurElements.toArray(new Integer[1]), other.elements)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
    }

}
```